# Replace all occurrences of the substring using slicing when size of replacement string the differs from substring

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I want to replace all substring occurrences in a string, but I wish not to use the replace method. It's just study interest. At the moment, experiments have led me to this:

```
def count_substrings_and_replace(string, substring, rpl=None):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    rpl_size = len(rpl)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, string_size + rpl_size):
        if string[i:i + substring_size] == substring:
            if rpl:
                string = string[:i] + rpl + string[i + substring_size:]
            count += 1
    return count, string
```

I figured out that it works not for any size of `rpl`.

For example for `count_substrings_and_replace("aaaQaaa", "aaa", "dddddd")` I have output:

`(2, 'ddddddQdddddd')`, alright

but if `rpl` takes a larger size, for example: `count_substrings_and_replace("aaaQaaaQaaa", "aaa", "ddddddddd")` I have output:

`(2, 'dddddddddQdddddddddQaaa')`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In your first input example, my output is `(2, 'ddddddQdddddd')` with the same code

Comment: @etch_45 oh. yea, my mistake. I will fix it now

Comment: @etch_45 maybe `for i in range(0, string_size * int(rpl_size/2)):` will good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same `string` variable and thus changing the size of it. In your example, each time that you replace `aaa` by ``dddddddd`, your string is longer, and` range(0, string_size + rpl_size)` is outdated.

```
def count_substrings_and_replace(string, substring, rpl=None):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    rpl_size = len(rpl)

    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < string_size:
        if string[i:i + substring_size] == substring:
            if rpl:
                string = string[:i] + rpl + string[i + substring_size:]
                string_size += rpl_size - substring_size
                # this is important to avoid replacement of substrings
                # contained in rpl, e.g. `aaa` and `aaaaaaaa`
                i += rpl_size
            count += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return count, string
```

But, it would be much easier if you just store the result in a new variable and forget about the slicing part.

```
def count_substrings_and_replace(string, substring, rpl=None):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    result = ''
    
    while i < len(string):
        if string[i:i + len(substring)] == substring:
            result += rpl
            count += 1
            i += len(substring)
        else: 
            result += string[i]
            i += 1
    return count, result
```